# Citation in biblatex produce an error resulting in missing bibliography

Tags: latex, bibliography, biblatex

I am getting an error `Citation 'McMahon2012' on page 1 undefined`, and hence there is no bibliography printed at the end. I am using biblatex and structured my file after (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_biblatex#Basic_usage).

Here is the minimal example:

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

Testing citation here \cite{McMahon2012}. 

\printbibliography %[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

references.bib

```
@article{McMahon2012,
   abstract = {Hydrogen and helium are the most abundant elements in the Universe. They are also, in principle, the most simple. Nonetheless, they display remarkable properties under extreme conditions of pressure and temperature that have fascinated theoreticians and experimentalists for over a century. Advances in computational methods have made it possible to elucidate ever more of their properties. Some of these methods that have been applied in recent years, in particular, those that perform simulations directly from the physical picture of electrons and ions, such as density functional theory and quantum Monte Carlo are reviewed. The predictions from such methods as applied to the phase diagram of hydrogen, with particular focus on the solid phases and the liquid-liquid transition are discussed. The predictions of ordered quantum states, including the possibilities of a low- or zero-temperature quantum fluid and high-temperature superconductivity are also considered. Finally, pure helium and hydrogen-helium mixtures, the latter which has particular relevance to planetary physics, are discussed. © 2012 American Physical Society.},
   author = {Jeffrey M. McMahon and Miguel A. Morales and Carlo Pierleoni and David M. Ceperley},
   doi = {10.1103/RevModPhys.84.1607},
   issn = {00346861},
   issue = {4},
   journal = {Reviews of Modern Physics},
   month = {11},
   title = {The properties of hydrogen and helium under extreme conditions},
   volume = {84},
   year = {2012},
}
```

The files references.bib and main.tex lie in the same directory

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. How do you compile your document? Do you run `biber`?